# Installing R on RHEL 7

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, r

I'm trying to install R on RHEL 7. I'm using epel-release-7-2.noarch.rpm and resolved many dependencies (one by one by manual .rpm installation) but at the end of the dependency resolution I got these errors:

`--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-7.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(dvips)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.1.1-7.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: texinfo-tex
Error: Package: R-java-devel-3.1.1-7.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: java-devel
Error: Package: R-core-3.1.1-7.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(latex)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.1.1-7.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(latex)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`

I'm using a system not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management, so I can't use subscription-manager to register it and resolving dependencies.

Where can I find tex(dvips) and tex(latex)? I'm trying to download it from mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ but I still haven't found the correct files

**Update:** 
Finally I've resolved myself the problem updating the RHEL repo:

`cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
vi CentOS-base.repo
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever – Base
baseurl=http://buildlogs.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64-20140704-1/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
priority=1
exclude=php mysql`

And after that:

`yum update
yum install texlive
yum install R`

...and a clean installation done! :)

Comment: if you solved the problem is valid to post your own answer and mark it as the right one

Comment: Do you know how can I check what's the newest available version of R for RHEL 7?

Answer (score 11):

I think installing R on CentOS 7 is simplest this way:

```
sudo yum install -y epel-release 
sudo yum update -y 
sudo yum install -y R
```

Comment: I think the premise of the question was that the OP was having dependency problems even though he was using epel-release.

Answer (score 8):

If you do not wish to install the CentOS repos, you can hand pick the individual packages that are required:

OS RHEL 7

```
 [ec2-user ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
 Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
```

IMPORTANT: Verify that EPEL repo was installed and configured as expected.
However, when installing R, there are still dependency problems:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum install R
… output truncated …
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.3.1-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
       Requires: texinfo-tex
```

There is no package for this in the Redhat or EPEL repositories. I grabbed one from CentOS7 repo.

```
[ec2-user ~]$ wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/texinfo-tex-5.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

And tried to install that but got another dependency problem…

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum localinstall texinfo-tex-5.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
… output truncated …
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: texinfo-tex-5.1-4.el7.x86_64 (/texinfo-tex-5.1-4.el7.x86_64)
       Requires: tex(epsf.tex)
```

Again, nothing in EPEL or RedHat, so I grabbed another couple of CentOS7 packages:

```
[ec2-user ~]$ wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/texlive-epsf-doc-svn21461.2.7.4-38.el7.noarch.rpm
[ec2-user ~]$ wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/texlive-epsf-svn21461.2.7.4-38.el7.noarch.rpm
```

So now I install the downloaded local packages

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum localinstall texlive-epsf-doc-svn21461.2.7.4-38.el7.noarch.rpm
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum localinstall texlive-epsf-svn21461.2.7.4-38.el7.noarch.rpm
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum localinstall texinfo-tex-5.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

And finally…

```
[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum install R
…output truncated…
Complete!
```

HTH

Comment: Tried multiple different options, and this was the ONLY one that actually worked for us with Redhat.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Excellent.

Comment: Links are now broken; check http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/ for latest

Answer (score 6):

BTW: to the ones who have a subscription and want to stay on the RHEL repositories therefore, will find the missing packages in 
"rhel-7-server-optional-rpms".

So `yum --enablerepo=epel --enablerepo="rhel-7-server-optional-rpms" install R` 
worked for me.

You might have to do a `subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-optional-rpms`.

Answer (score 3):

For those looking for a straight answer, R belongs to RHEL Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL), therefore:

```
su -c 'rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm'

sudo yum update

sudo yum install R
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are installing on Redhat, you just need to local install 'textinfo-tex' and 'textlive-epsf-svn' from CentOS repo, and then install R from epel replease repo.