# Installing R on RHEL 7.4

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, r, rhel-7

I've checked this one [Installing R on RHEL 7](https://superuser.com/questions/841270/installing-r-on-rhel-7) but it's not solving my problem.

When I run

> yum install R

I ended up with some dependencies error as below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install R
```

somehow conda can install R without bothering without the dependency issues.